# Is there a way to understand why K-Means uses a specific variable for clustering?

Tags: r, k-means

I'm very new to R and clustering and currently I am working on a homework. The task is to cluster the data of a housing company, in order to understand and adjust it's business model better, based on the results.

The original dataset can be found [here](https://file.io/nrFkqBKPiMny).
I removed a few of the columns, because (according to the homework) they aren't relevant.
It looks like this in R:
[image]

I used K-Means in order to perform the clustering.

```
#use Elbow Method in order to understand how many clusters are needed.
set.seed(123)

fviz_nbclust(clustering, kmeans, method = "wss")

#perform k-means
k2 <- kmeans(clustering, centers = 10, nstart = 25)
str(k2)

fviz_cluster(k2, data = clustering)
```

The result is:
[image]

It looks like K-Means uses **sqft_lot** to create the clusters. Is this a variable, which has been chosen automatically by the algorithm or can I choose and set the variable for the clustering manually? I am just not sure if **sqft_lot** is the best option.

At the moment I'm not quite satisfied with the result. I am not sure if it really delivers valuable information in it's current form.

Comment: It seems to me you should first figure out what your result is supposed to look like before you start writing your script. What information do you want to get? Also, what did you try? What error messages did you get? Did you read the r documentation for k-means clustering? -- PS your link is dead.

Comment: How do you conclude that kmeans "uses sqft_lot to create the clusters"? Are you confusing the clustering algorithm with its visualization by `fviz_cluster`?

Comment: @D.J Sorry, I fixed the dead link. Thanks for asking these questions. On the one hand, I expected the algorithm to cluster the housing data into clusters according to the similarities of the data. On the other hand I also started writing the script and wanted to see what the result is going to be and see if I'm in heading in the right direction. I haven't gotten any errors so far. I also tried Hierarchical Clustering before k-means, but plotting the data was an issue so I went for k-means.

Comment: @cdalitz I am not 100% sure, but I assume this since the plotted values (e.g. 8093, 7253, 3915) are all values from the "sqft_lot" column. If the values are coming from the algorithm itself, what do they mean / why would the be displayed as "random" numbers? How to interpret them correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the numbers printed for each point are IDs, not values of any of the columns. Dim1 & Dim2 are the first 2 principal components from PCA; they're not directly the columns in your data frame. K-means uses all of the columns you give it as input, not just one. It might help to first read through some overviews of how k-means clustering works and how to make decisions with it such as whether the information is useful for whatever your purposes are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the clustering with the two dimensional projection in the plot. The clustering uses all dimesnions, but in the plot the 8-dimensional data points are projected onto a 2-dimensional space.

Such projection methods are called "multidimensional scaling" (MDS). There are different algorithms for MDS, but presumably `fviz` uses PCA, a method that projects onto the two directions with the highest variance. As `sqft_lot` is the variable with the highest variance, it dominates one of the directions in the projected space.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed clarification! After spending one more day on this, I definitely can confirm that you are right: I was confusing the clustering with the two dimensional projection in the plot.